# spring state machine "dynamic fork"

Tags: spring, spring-statemachine

I'm trying to model a business process using the spring state machine. So far I've been very sucessful with it but I'm stuck on trying to model a dynamic bit, where

- the user is in state **A**
- in that state he can create a short (predefined) task for a different user (a small state machine)
- those users have to basically execute a state machine flow til the end
- it should be possible to spawn many tasks concurently.
- the user returns to state **A** once all created by him tasks have completed.

Here is a graphical representation of what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: Image of the desired state machien diagram]

I think I could do this if I represent each task as a state machine and so on but I would prefer to avoid going that route as it would complicate the application. Ideally I would have just one state machine configuration.

In the spring reference I found the fork pseudo state to be maybe what I'm looking for however the offical example repo only covers a static configuration (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/master/docs/src/reference/asciidoc/sm-examples.adoc#statemachine-examples-tasks) where each tasks are already defined (T1, T2, T3). For my application needs however I would want to be able to (at runtime) add "T4".

In essence I would like to know whether my requirements could be fullfilled with a single state machine and if I could use fork() for my needs. If its not the case I will welcome any advice that would push me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm on mobile right know so could look this further next week.  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/master/spring-statemachine-recipes/src/main/java/org/springframework/statemachine/recipes/tasks/TasksHandler.java shows some concept to build these type of machines dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented over the weekend, if you need a "dynamic" configuration then easiest way to do it is using "dynamic builder interfaces" which is same as in all other examples. It was basically added to be able to use SSM outside of a spring application context. Tasks recipe uses this model as it supports running a DAG of tasks using hierarchical regions and submachines.

You don't necessarily need fork as if parallel regions are entered using initial states it is equivalent. You however need join to wait parallel regions to join their execution.

While that recipe provide some background how thins can be done, we have hopefully something better in our roadmap which is supposed to add a dsl language which should make these kind of custom implementations a much easier to make.