# How to create dynamic sub-states in state machine?

Tags: java, spring, state-machine, spring-statemachine

I'm new to State machine. Could you explain, it's possible to create dynamic sub-states (pseudo states) in @Configuration classes with application context, or it's possible only by Builder?

For example: I have initial state READY, fork state FORK, parent state TASK and several sub-task states, the number of which is dynamic (T1-T1E, T2-T2E, ...). Sub tasks are executed in parallel.

```
@Override
public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, Events> states)
        throws Exception {
    states
        .withStates()
            .initial(States.READY)
            .fork(States.FORK)
            .state(States.TASKS)
            .join(States.JOIN)          
            .state(States.ERROR)
            .and()
            .withStates()
                .parent(States.TASKS)
                .initial(States.T1)
                .end(States.T1E)
                .and()
            .withStates()
                .parent(States.TASKS)
                .initial(States.T2)
                .end(States.T2E)
                .and()
            .withStates()
                .parent(States.TASKS)
                .initial(States.T3)
                .end(States.T3E)
                .and()
                                 ....
                              // dynamic sub-task
                                 ....  
 
}
```

In a moment when State machine hasn't started I have no information, how many sub-states (sub tasks T1-T1E....)I have to create. I will get this information, when be on FORK state.
How to configure that in Spring context?

I've found an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48830885/spring-state-machine-dynamic-fork) when configuration was creating by Builder, outside the Spring application context.

If you know how to do that in Spring context, I will be grateful for your help.